# Xamarin Emulator - System UI isn`t responding

Tags: c#, xamarin, mobile

I am new to Xamarin development but want to learn the basics. I can't make my android emulator Pixel 3 x86 Android 9 Pie to open and see the very default app. System UI isn`t responding is the main error. I tried almost everything I've found online. I have considered installing an older version of VS but I am not sure. Can you help please?

Comment: Post exactly error

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO ! You need to check whehter [install the needed full packages of SDK in Xamarin Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=windows#platforms-tab) .

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT did that and it`s still not working

Comment: @ValentinMarian First ,Close your simulator then re-start application .Second , whether it can start Simulator .Third , whether it can start Application . By the way , you need to share the full error log in question .